# Selecting dynamic element which is not visible in HTML

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am having trouble selecting an element, because it dynamically generates on response to the user selecting an option from a dropdown.

Example, a user selects "Menu Sets" from a dropdown list, when this is done a "New" button appears on a toolbar (ID:d_toolbar_toolbar)

This is different dependant on the selection, and does not appear in the html when i inspect it with I.E. developer tools.

I have looked at the source of the webpage and I have located the below which appears to be dynamically adding this onto the toolbar dependant on the selection, with Javascript

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
<td height="24">
<?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX="TBNS" /><?IMPORT NAMESPACE="TBNS"  IMPLEMENTATION="/webctrl_client/1_0/toolbar.htc" />
<TBNS:Toolbar id="d_toolbar_toolbar" class="standarddarkrow" oncheckchange="javascript:toolbarButtonClicked('{0}','{1}','False',-1,13, true, 'd:toolbar:toolbar')" oncheckchange="JScript:if (event.srcNode != null) __d_toolbar_toolbar_State__.value+=((event.srcNode.getAttribute('selected')=='true')?'+':'-')+event.flatIndex+';';" onbuttonclick="JScript:if (event.srcNode != null) if ((event.srcNode.getType() != 'checkbutton') || (event.srcNode.getAttribute('_autopostback') != null)) if (getAttribute('_submitting') != 'true'){setAttribute('_submitting', 'true');try{__doPostBack('d$toolbar$toolbar',event.flatIndex);}catch(e){setAttribute('_submitting', 'false');}}" onwcready="JScript:try{__d_toolbar_toolbar_State__.value = ''}catch(e){}" defaultstyle="color:black;border:solid 1px #E0E3EA;background:#E0E3EA;padding:0px;" hoverstyle="border:solid 1px #416791;background:#E0E3EA;margin:0px;padding:0px;" selectedstyle="color:black;border:solid 1px #E0E3EA;background:#E0E3EA;padding:0px;" style="border-width:0px;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:8pt;">
<TBNS:ToolbarButton ID="New" imageUrl="http://www.starchef.net/skins/default/new.gif"  onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13){event.returnValue=false}">New</TBNS:ToolbarButton>
```

I have tried to select by an ID of New but this has not worked, I presume i need to select the d_toolbar_toolbar element and then do something further to select the New, but I can’t work out how.

Comment: Try debugging it on Goole Chrome and jQuery.

Comment: Any url for us to check?

Comment: As you said, the element is created dynamically, try to traverse to it from its parent which is static and check.

Comment: The site is only compatible with I.E. and I cant post the full url as it requires login credentials. Is there a way I can select <TBNS:ToolbarButton ID="New"> using xpath or css ?

Comment: The <TBNS is a little different than standard html.  Without having access to the site I would recommend this approach.  1)try `//TBNS` and see if you can find any of them.  2) if so then try `//TBNS[@ID="New"]`...if not then I would try to find the specific cell that this resides in and then do `/TBNS[2]`.  3) if that still doesn't work then I would recommend using the `/following-sibling::TBNS` approach.  It would be great to get access to this one page if possible to help you further, but I understand proprietary content restrictions exist here.  Please respond with your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these elements did not exist in the DOM, resolved by selecting the main element and then using the movebyoffset action to click.

```
    public void ClickNewMenuSet()
    {
        var element = _driver.FindElement(By.Id(("d_toolbar_toolbar")));
        var actions = new Actions(_driver);
        actions.Click(element).MoveByOffset(-450, 0).Click().Build().Perform();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must test for a specific "state" of the application.  That means that you will need to save the specific maps and test their existence/absence based on the dropdown selection values.  This is where a wrapper or various layers are important because you won't know until it throws an error for not finding something.  A function that verifies a successful error is thrown and then returns a boolean value is the best way I have found to simply do this.

```
//if (dropdown option value == x)
    if (ElementExists(By.XPath(xpathHiddenElement))
      //log what you want to or do some other check
    else
      //log what you want to or do some other check

public bool ElementExists(By by)
{
    try
    {
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Personally I do alot more than just this in mine, but I usually have multiple layers and complexities and error handling and results involved.  This is a simple example to just find if an element exists or not without breaking your test.

Comment: I am simply trying to navigate to the new button and click on it to navigate to the next screen, as far as i can see this is, standarddarkrow"
<TBNS:ToolbarButton ID="New" imageUrl="http://www.starchef.net/skins/default/new.gif" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13){event.returnValue=false}">New</TBNS:ToolbarButton> The above code is not going to let me select this ?

Comment: your map for your button goes in the `xpathHiddenElement` spot.  That will tell you if the button exists or not without killing your test.  Then if it returns true then you can execute your click on it.  If it's false you can change your dropdown selection so you know the button is there and then click it.

Comment: if you need help with the actual selection that would be utilized in the `xpathHiddenElement` then it would help to provide a little more html...you can delete the contents and just give the tag structure with some identifiable attributes.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the full HTML, thankyou.

Comment: These did not work unfortuantley, afte speaking to a colleauge the only way we worked out how to do this was by selecting the main  element and then using new Actions(_driver);
            actions.Click(element).MoveByOffset(-450, 0).Click().Build().Perform(); to manually move and select the button.